# How to bowl a big leg break?

Tags: cricket

I think I have understood the grip of leg break ("two fingers up and two down"), but I am having problems understanding how to release the ball; when to uncock my wrist, where will my palm face while releasing the ball. etc.

What's the most effective way to bowl a leg break?